# Magento 2 - how do i redirect "mydomain/pub" and "mydomain/pub/media" path to homepage?

Tags: magento2, redirect, htaccess, .htaccess, redirection

I'm trying to redirect "mydomain.com/pub" and "www.mydomain.com/pub/media" to homepage (mydomain.com). 
Currently, "mydomain.com/pub" path shows the homepage with no css and js loaded, and "www.mydomain.com/pub/media/" path shows the directory listing page for all the media files.

I am trying to direct both paths to the magento home page.

The solution from here does not work for my purpose ( changing the 404 redirection in admin panel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048263/how-can-i-redirect-404-pages-to-home-page-in-magento-community )